# Reference for the Banach Manifold structure of $C^k(M,N)$

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, textbook-recommendation, banach-manifold

I'm completely new to the subject of banach manifolds and I'm looking for a reference of the following:

> Let $M$,$N$ be smooth (=$C^\infty$) finite-dimensional compact manifolds. Consider the set $C^k(M,N)$ of $C^k$-maps from $M$ to $N$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $k<\infty$. Then there exsists the structure of a smooth banach manifold on $C^k(M,N)$ and the underlying topology is the compact-open $C^k$-topology (the weak topology).

So far, I was only able to find references that prove more general results (and thus the proofs get harder and use things I don't really need for now), e.g. if $N$ is a banach manifold itself. These stronger results I found in:

- Eliasson, *Geometry of Manifolds of Maps*
- Abraham, *Lectures of Smale on Differential Topology*

Other sources I found deal only with $C^\infty(M,N)$ or $C^0(M,N)$.
In this context the books of Lang (e.g. *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry*) are mentioned (e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37482/manifolds-of-continuous-mappings?rq=1)), but I'm not able to find these parts in his books.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could name me a reference where the above statement is proven.

Comment: You can find proofs of these statements in the notes of John Moore found at the following link:  http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~moore/globalanalysisshort.pdf.

Comment: Let me refine that by saying that I don't think there is any mention of the compact-open topology there, just so I don't send you on a wild goose chase.  Nonetheless, you'll find the proof that it is a smooth Banach manifold.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! I have a follow-up question, maybe you (or someone else) can help me with it: Can the tangent bundle of the smooth banach manifold $C^k(M,N)$ be realised as $\bigcup_{f\in C^k(M,N)}C^k(f^*TN)\rightarrow C^k(M,N)$ where a $C^k$-section $X\in C^k(f^*TN)$ is mapped to $f$? If so, what's the idea to prove that?

Comment: See this paper for the formal details http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.3111v2.pdf.  Then, just note that if $f_t:M\rightarrow N$ is a variation of $f,$ then the first variation is a section of $f^{*}TN.$

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Maybe I can ask one last question.

In the notes you linked me, the $C^\infty$ structure on $C^k(M,N)$ is consctructed like that: Pick $f\in C^\infty(M,N)$, then use the exponential map to construct a chart $x_f:U_f\rightarrow V_f$ where $U_f$ is a neighborhood of $f$ in $C^k(M,N)$. Then it is shown that for another $g\in C^\infty (M,N)$, the transition maps $x_f\circ x_g^{-1}$ are smooth.

Other sources I found seem to indicate that this works aswell for $f,g \in C^k(M,N)$, i.e. for $f,g \in C^k(M,N)$ the transtion map $x_f\circ x_g^{-1}$ is smooth. Is that true?

Comment: You've probably already got an answer by now, but in case you haven't you can find it here: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf theorem 42.1